# Reactjs+Typescript: access chaining types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For enums, i can create this command line: enums.login.form

But for types, i can't create chaining access to types: types.login.form

> logix.tsx:

```
namespace login {
export type form = {
mobile: string;
}
}

export default login
```

> index.tsx

```
import * as _login from './login';

namespace types {
export import login = _login;
}

export default types;
```

> app.tsx

```
import types from '../types';

const Form = ({ mobile }: types.login.default.form) => {
}
```

everything is ok, but `default` does not need

i want this: `types.login.form`
not this: `types.login.default.form`

Comment: Your question seem all over the place, could you please review.  It's really unclear what your asking.  `For enums, `,, what enums?,  `from '../types';` This seems related to nothing in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly `export namespace login` in *login.ts*.

```
export namespace login {
  export type form = {
    mobile: string;
  }
}
```

`export * as default from "./login"` in *index.ts*.

And `import types from "./index"` in *app.tsx*. That allows you to access `form` in *app.tsx* (which was originally defined in `login.ts`) as follows:

```
import types from "./index";

const Form = ({mobile}: types.login.form) => {
  // Your code here
};
```

Comment: thank you, but i dont want to use *: `import * as types from "./index";` i want to use `import types from "./index";`

Comment: Please take a look at my edit and consider editing your question as well. It states `import types from '../types';` but there is no `types.ts` file in your question.

Comment: how about multiple export in index.tsx? `export * as default from "./login"
export * as default from "./register"` and ...